# Dropdown Toggle with AngularJS That Closes on Click Elsewhere

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Implementing a simple dropdown directive that uses ng-show to show or hide a menu is trivial in AngularJS.  I want to also close the menu if the user clicks elsewhere in the screen after having opened the menu.  What is the simplest possible correct way to do this? I have tried using $document.bind and $document.unbind to unbind from the document afterwards, but it does not seem to work as expected, and I can't work ought how it ought to work due to questions of scoping.

I'm aware the ui-bootstrap has a similar directive (dropdownToggle), and I've dug through the source of it, but it looks much more complicated and introduces a dependency on an older version of bootstrap.

Here is an [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BfnkzitfTzehU5S1e1PM?p=preview) (that does not close the menu on click elsewhere).

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="plunker" >
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="///netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div  ng-app="dropdown">
      <div menu-status-widget></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: seems to be a problem adding a document clcik handler within ng-click. Use own click handler. can use [angular-ui dropdown code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdownToggle/dropdownToggle.js) as reference

Comment: @charlietfl the document click handler does work; If I drop an alert in it, I get an alert when I click elsewhere.

Comment: what i experienced was the document clcik handler seems to fire as soon as you bind it within `ng-click`. WHen using external events that angular isn't aware of to change scope, you have to change the scope within `$.apply` which triggers  digest . Once you do this using the `'ng-clcik` approach, the menu never open...the 2 cancel each other

Comment: that's why I suggest following pattern the angular-ui folks use and avoid `ng-click`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to handle situation using `ng-click`. You need to pass `$event` argument into your `ng-click` function so can call `$event.stopPropagation()`

`ng-click` doesn't seem to react the same way a jQuery handler would. It seems to actually trigger the event after all the code is run, so this causes the `$document` handler you just added to actually fire.

```
<div ng-click="buttonAction($event)" >
```

```
    scope.buttonAction = function($event) {
              $event.stopPropagation()
                if (!scope.showMenu) {
                    var closeMe = function(scope) { 
                      scope.showMenu = false;
                      $document.unbind('click', this);
                    };
                    $document.bind('click', function(event) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                       closeMe(scope)
                    })
                      }); 
                    scope.showMenu = true;
                } else {
                    scope.showMenu = false;
                } 
            };
```

In my mind it is simpler to forget about `ng-click` and just use `element.bind`. Either way you still have to use `scope.$apply()` to change scope so angular runs a digest

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bAYOM8S2OE7C3a3RGHls?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the extra explanation.

Comment: your previous comment made a light go off...I actually played with this for about 1/2 hour the other day and got frustrated with `ng-clcik` ...forgot you could pass `$event` to it

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate directives.

With this way you don't have to touch the original code and you can keep the original behaviour.

You can put a close button inside the dropdown

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu keep-dropdown-open-on-click" role="menu">
    <i class="icon-close close-dropdown-on-click"></i>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app').config(uiDropdownMenuDecorate);
uiDropdownMenuDecorate.$inject = ['$provide'];
function uiDropdownMenuDecorate($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('dropdownMenuDirective', uiDropdownMenuDecorator);

    uiDropdownMenuDecorator.$inject = ['$delegate'];

    function uiDropdownMenuDecorator($delegate) {

        var directive = $delegate[0];
        var link = directive.link;

        directive.compile = function () {
            return function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                link.apply(this, [scope, elem, attrs, ctrl]);
                elem.click(function (e) {
                    if (elem.hasClass('keep-dropdown-open-on-click') && !angular.element(e.target).hasClass('close-dropdown-on-click')) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                });
            };
        };

        return $delegate;
    }
}
```